# Calling python script in web2py framework over webserver

Tags: python, nginx, web2py

I have NGINX UWSGI and WEB2PY installed on the server. Web2py application performing only one function by accessing the database and printing rows in the table.

```
def fetch():

    import psycopg2

    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres",
                    user="postgres",
                    password="qwerty",
                    host="127.0.0.1")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id, name from TEST")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

When the function is called locally the table contents is returned.
But when I'm trying to call the function from remote machine I get an internal error 500.

One more interesting thing, is when function looks like this:

```
def hello():
    return 'hello'
```

String 'hello' is returned. Starting adding it an import directive immediately causes error page to be generated.

Can any one please suggest the proper application syntax/logic?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your MySQL service doesn't allow remote access. Could you check your MySQL configuration?

```
vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment out the following lines.

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
#skip-networking
```

If there is no skip-networking line in your configuration file, just add it and comment out it.

And then restart the mysql service.

```
service mysql restart
```

Comment: I'm using postgresql. Application is accessed via uwsgi. As far I understand web2py framework logic, I'm calling application by accessing http://server/app_dir/src_file/func    
It works for me if I simply want to return 'hello'. And I able to get the string using a getresponse() method from httplib library on remote machine.

I think I'm looking for a way to return integers or arrays?

Comment: And it is just a function that called remotely access to the database is local. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the stupid question but have you checked if the module is available on your server?

When you say that the error appears in your hello function as soon as you try to import, it's the same directive `import psycopg2`?

Try this:
Assuming that fetch() it's defined on `controllers/default.py`
open folder `views/default` and create a new file called `fetch.html`
paste this inside

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=rows}}
```

fetch.html is a view or a template if you prefer

Modify fetch() to return a dictionary with rows for the view to print

```
return dict(rows=rows)
```

this is very basic tough, you can find more information about basic steps in the book -> http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#Postbacks

Comment: Yes. But it is ok if I'm trying to access the DB on the server it self, but not via web.
I think I don't understand web2py application logic and thats why cann't proper return the data. Something with calling conventions.

Comment: Web2py logic it's simple, invoking functions from localhost returns a generic view, if you are on a 'real' server you have to provide your own view.
Not sure if a missing view may return an error 500. Any chance to have  a look at those rows?